# Why does ecto can't preload query with 'Group by'?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm developping a chat.
I have many rooms, withs members in these rooms. Users can also join multiples rooms so it's a many to many relationship.
I want to get a room, preload it's members and for each member, count the number unread messages he has.

Here is the request i'm trying to do in ecto:

```
room_id = "general"

members_preload = from u in User,
                  join: ru in RoomUser, on: ru.user_id == u.id,
                  join: r in Room, on: r.id == ru.room_id,
                  where: r.room_id == ^room_id,
                  left_join: m in Message, on: m.room_id == ru.room_id,
                  where: m.inserted_at > ru.last_read,
                  group_by: [u.id, ru.id],
                  select_merge: %{role: ru.role, number_unread_messages: count(m.id)}

query = from r in Room,
        where: r.room_id == ^room_id,
        preload: [users: ^members_preload]
```

But this return me this error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42803 (grouping_error) column "r4.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

query: SELECT u0."id", u0."user_id", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at", r1."role", count(m3."id"), r4."id" FROM "users" AS u0 INNER JOIN "room_users" AS r1 ON r1."user_id" = u0."id" INNER JOIN "rooms" AS r2 ON r2."id" = r1."room_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" AS m3 ON m3."room_id" = r1."room_id" INNER JOIN "rooms" AS r4 ON r4."id" = ANY($1) INNER JOIN "room_users" AS r5 ON r5."room_id" = r4."id" WHERE (r2."room_id" = $2) AND (m3."inserted_at" > r1."last_read") AND (r5."user_id" = u0."id") GROUP BY u0."id", r1."id" ORDER BY r4."id"

    (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:618: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
    (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:551: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:153: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:18: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:159: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:18: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/3
```

The things is that when i do the members_request only, it works well:

```
iex()> Repo.all(members_preload)

[
  %Core.Schema.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    id: "8d51949b-4f60-4a86-b035-054c6064264d",
    inserted_at: ~N[2019-07-12 15:13:12],
    number_unread_messages: 6,
    role: "member",
    room_id: nil,
    rooms: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :rooms is not loaded>,
    updated_at: ~N[2019-07-12 15:13:12],
    user_id: "Nils"
  },
  %Core.Schema.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    id: "cefb9fab-b281-4c00-9b98-2d8346576144",
    inserted_at: ~N[2019-07-12 15:13:12],
    number_unread_messages: 6,
    role: "member",
    room_id: nil,
    rooms: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :rooms is not loaded>,
    updated_at: ~N[2019-07-12 15:13:12],
    user_id: "John"
  }
]
```

How could i get this to work ?
Thanks by advance for yours answers.

Here are the schemas i use:

```
defmodule Core.Schema.Room do
  @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  @foreign_key_type :binary_id

  schema "rooms" do
    field :room_id, :string

    has_many :messages, Message
    many_to_many :users, User, join_through: "room_users"

    timestamps()
  end
end

defmodule Core.Schema.User do
  @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  @foreign_key_type :binary_id

  schema "users" do
    field :user_id, :string

    many_to_many :rooms, Room, join_through: "room_users"
    timestamps()
  end
end

defmodule Core.Schema.RoomUser do
  @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  @foreign_key_type :binary_id

  schema "room_users" do
    field :role, :string, default: "member"
    field :last_read, :naive_datetime_usec

    belongs_to :room, Room, primary_key: :room_id, type: :binary_id
    belongs_to :user, User, primary_key: :user_id, type: :binary_id

    timestamps()
  end
end

defmodule Core.Schema.Message do
  @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  @foreign_key_type :binary_id

  schema "messages" do
    field :text, :string

    belongs_to :room, Room
    belongs_to :user, User, primary_key: :user_id, type: :binary_id

    timestamps(type: :naive_datetime_usec)
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to tell [tag:ecto] your `members_preload` is a [`Subquery`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/2).

Comment: I told ecto members_preload is a [preload query](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
query = from r in Room,
        where: r.room_id == ^room_id,
        preload: [users: ^members_preload]
```

to this:

```
query = from r in Room,
        where: r.room_id == ^room_id,
        preload: [users: ^subquery(members_preload)]
```

Note a call to [`subquery`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.1.7/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/2) function. I believe this is what [**Aleksei Matiushkin**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/aleksei-matiushkin) mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039593/why-does-ecto-cant-preload-query-with-group-by#comment100607491_57039593).

This code will make association pre-loading ran as a second query. If you really need to keep a single query, try coming up with a pure SQL query first, then see if you can convert that to Ecto.